# Could an audio induction loop be used to transmit wi-fi?

Tags: induction

A few months ago, I built an audio induction loop around my house using the existing dog electric fence, and had great results, and could hear the music a small amount even 2 neighbors away. I used a coil to pickup the audio and a power audio amp to transmit. I am wondering if it would be possible to transmit wi-fi for a device to pick up. This seems like a good idea because the wifi would be easily picked up around the house, and would reduce by exponential factors outside of the house, preventing people from picking up the signal. To reduce the power transformer noise, I am guessing a high-pass filter could be installed on the receiving device. Would it be possible to do this? I am not saying easy, just possible, and would it be practical? It seems like a lot of bandwidth could be transferred through the induction loop because all frequencies could be available (except under 100 hertz because of the power transformer interference). The only disadvantages I see is the setup of the large wire, which would have to be placed around your house and the orientation of the pickup coil ( maybe an external coil would be plugged into your laptop or a self-rotating coil inside)

Would this be possible? Has this been considered? And if so, why is it not done today?

Comment: Not sure your WiFi devices will be able to hand-shake, given the added latency introduced by distance and by the RF power amplification device. Hence, while getting the RF signal out, or receiving it, are valid parts of the problem, timing is another issue that must be considered.

Answer (score 3):

Possible, yes. Useful, no.

An audio induction loop is a loop of wire around a room or building that is driven with baseband audio frequencies. Assuming we are talking about audio for humans, these frequencies are in the range of 20Hz to 20000Hz. Thus, the highest audible frequencies have a wavelength of about:

$$ \lambda = \frac{c}{f} = \frac{300 \cdot 10^6\:\mathrm{m/s}}{20000\:\mathrm{Hz}} = 15\:\mathrm{km}$$

It's unlikely any practical loop around a building will be anywhere near this large, so we can consider an audio induction loop to be a [small loop antenna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_antenna#Small_loops). This means that the time it takes an electric wave to travel around the loop is very small compared to the wavelength, so we can consider the current in the loop to be the same everywhere. Essentially, the audio induction loop is one half of an air-core transformer, with the other half being the receiving device, which must be in the [near field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_and_far_field) of the loop to function effectively.

On the other hand, of the many Wi-Fi standards, I don't believe any common standard operates at a frequency less than \$2.4GHz\$. The wavelength is approximately:

$$ \frac{300 \cdot 10^6 \:\mathrm{m/s}}{2.4\:\mathrm{GHz}} = 125\:\mathrm{mm} $$

This is orders of magnitude smaller than any imaginable audio induction loop. Thus, the current in the loop wouldn't be the same everywhere, because in the time of one cycle, the electric wave has propagated only a small distance around the loop.

This complicates the analysis of this antenna significantly. Analysis is especially complicated in the near field, because you will get a pattern of standing waves that work constructively in some locations, and destructively in others. The ordinary objects in a room will also interact with the antenna, refracting, reflecting, and absorbing the electric energy in the room, making any simple analysis not practical.

That's not to say it couldn't be done, but given that every Wi-Fi access point already has an antenna that does work, what would be the advantage?

Comment: I also forgot about upload, I only thought of download!

Comment: @skyler that's actually not so much of a problem, if you could solve all the others. If an antenna can transmit, it can usually receive as just as well. See [reciprocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocity_%28electromagnetism%29).

Comment: One could postulate that the audio loop would function somewhat like a lossy transmission line, and thereby radiate, even at 2.4 GHz. Unfortunately, the transmission losses of such an audio loop would be so staggeringly high, that there would be no useable signal power left after a few meters of transmission around the loop, so that the whole arrangement would only radiate effective power for a few meters at most.